# how to use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification

Tags: swift, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer, icloud-documents

Hi  I am trying to get event notification from NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to get notification if data change or not?

> NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.eventChangedNotification

but I didn't find any simple example how to use it. doesnt any know to use this notification to handle the errors.